# Fix deposit and USER-REAXC: pre-allocating memory for atoms when using LAMMPS with ReaxFF

Tags: molecular-dynamics, high-performance-computing, lammps, software-assistance, forcefields

I would like to use "[fix deposit](https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/fix_deposit.html)" with ReaxFF to add atoms to a simulation in which I deposit molecules on a surface.

I have built working scripts for my system with other force fields. However, there is an issue with the ReaxFF implementation in LAMMPS where depositing new molecules into a system will cause an error [(too many ghost atoms](https://lammps.sandia.gov/threads/msg66005.html)). As per the link, the error most likely arises because the USER-REAXC package pre-allocates memory for atoms based on the initial number of atoms in the simulation box.

I do know the maximum number of atoms needed before the simulation starts. I am looking for a workaround for this issue, which would allow me to pre-allocate memory for this number of atoms, which I can later add to the simulation box.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our site and thank you for asking your question here! We hope to see much more of you !!!

Comment: Hi geo! Is there any update about this question? It's a great one indeed!

Comment: Related question on MatSci forum: https://matsci.org/t/problems-with-simulation-of-thermal-degradation/26844